# Kann das Wort "Entschuldigung" eine Frage oder Bitte einleiten?

Tags: word-usage

Ich bin Italienerin und arbeite seit kurzer Zeit in Deutschland. Bisher habe ich immer

> Entschuldigung

gesagt, wenn jemand vor mir stand und ich durchgehen wollte... also so wie auf Englisch

> Sorry, can I get past?

Es scheint mir aber, dass meine Kollegen es nicht so verstehen. Sie haben mir sogar gesagt: "Du musst dich nicht immer entschuldigen!"

Habe ich den Gebrauch dieses Wortes missverstanden?

Comment: Du hast merkwürdige Kollegen. Versuche es doch mal mit „Platz da!“ ;)

Comment: Leute machen sich oft einen "Spaß" daraus anderen zu sagen, sich nicht so oft zu entschuldigen. Aber ich glaube sie selbst nutzen das Wort ganz genau so, ohne es zu merken.

Comment: Höflichkeit kann manchmal zu viel sein oder sogar nerven. Es ist situationsbezogen anzuwenden. Unter Fremden sehr zu empfehlen, unter Freunden wird das eher weggekürzt. Wahrscheinlich trifft bei dir Fall 2 zu.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ja, es kann so genutzt werden. Allerdings würde ich es als eine höfliche/förmliche Variante bezeichnen.

Also hier mal vier Varianten von `darf ich mal durch` und was ich nutzen würde:

1. An öffentlichen Plätzen. (Unbekannte Menschen) Dort nutze ich meist `Entschuldigung!`, manchmal nach einer Sprechpause gefolgt von `Darf ich mal durch?` Aber nur, wenn die Leute das nicht verstehen. In der Öffentlichkeit wissen die meisten, was man meint, wenn man sich bemerkbar macht.
2. Bei Bekannten Personen. Dort nutze ich `Darf ich mal vorbei?` / `Kannst du mich mal vorbei lassen?`, etc. Entschuldigung nutze ich dort nur in einer umgangssprachlichen Variante: `Tschuldigung`, oder einfach `Sorry`.
3. Bei sehr nahestenden Personen. Leute, mit denen ich sehr locker umgehe (enge Freunde), da darf alles dabei sein. Von `Kann ich mal bitte vorbei?`, über `Lässt du mich mal durch?` bis hin zu `Lass mich vorbei!`
4. **Ergänzung:** Von alten Leuten oder bei sehr sehr förmlichen Anlässen. `Verzeihung` hört man oft von älteren Menschen. Ich persönlich würde es allerdings nur an sehr förmlichen Anlässen nutzen.. also derzeit nie ;-)

Es kommt also ein wenig auf die Situation an. Ich persönlich finde ein `(Entschuldigung -) kann ich mal vorbei?` nie verkehrt. Aber da kenne ich keine klaren Regeln.

Comment: Ich würde gerne +10 geben, besonders für Punkt 1. Ich sage in der Bahn oder so auch oft nur "Tschuldigung" und der Kontext macht den Rest. Aber + 10 geht nicht also -1... alles oder nichts ;)

Comment: Ich denke, das "Entschuldigung!" dient dazu, die Aufmerksamkeit derer, an denen man vorbeimöchte, auf sich zu lenken, wenn die gerade mit etwas anderem beschäftigt sind. Wenn ich durch den vollen Zug laufe, und jemand, der mir im Weg steht, mit dem Rücken zu mir steht und sich unterhält, sage ich "Entschuldigung, darf ich mal bitte durch?". Wenn ich aber quer durch eine Warteschlange möchte und schon Blickkontakt mit jemandem darin habe, reicht "Darf ich da bitte mal durch?".

Comment: Im Karneval oder bei feucht-fröhlichen Festen: "Vorsicht! Heiß und Fettig!" oder "Mutter mit Kind!" oder "Ich bin Arzt!".

Comment: @userunknown Ich bin durch, laß mich Arzt