# Best phrase to use when passing by someone in your path/way?

Tags: phrase

I do hear *Entschuldigung* a lot in this case, but what other words or phrases are there to politely excuse yourself while brushing past someone?

Comment: Not so polite forms: "Aus dem Weg!", "Heiß und fettig!", "Mutter mit Kind!", "Lasst mich vor, ich bin Arzt!".

Comment: "Tüt-tüt!"... sehr umgangssprachlich und weder besonders höflich noch besonders unhöflich.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also say:

> Verzeihung
>   Pardon
>   Sorry

And you can put an “Oh, …” at the beginning of your excuse.

Comment: And "Danke!" if the other person steps aside or "Darf ich bitte (durch)?" for those remaining in your way.

Comment: How does Verzeihung come across vs Pardon and Sorry?

Comment: In my opinion Verzeihung and Pardon are the most polite expressions,  Entschuldigung is poilte, too and Sorry may be a bit lapidary, but this may vary from region to region. The English and French words are widely used - at least by people under 50 years ;-)

Comment: @hellcode: this would also make a useful addendum to your great answer.

Comment: Thanks hellcode. Another question, would Oh, Pardon have the same register as it has in English?

Comment: Pronunciation note: _Pardon_ is not pronounced as in English; instead, either more or less as in French, or like _Pardong_ (in any case stressed on the second syllable).

Comment: "Pardon" wird vor allem in West- und Süddeutschland verwendet, im Norten und Osten ist es weniger Verbreitet. Generell, sind einige französische Begriffe in Rheinland-Pfalz, Saarland und Südhessen sehr verbreitet. (Trottoir[Sprich Trottwa] für "Gehsteig", oder Portmonee für "Geldbörse")

Comment: @shinninja For me "Verzeihung" sounds much more polite than the rest and I prefer it. "Sorry" sounds very informal.

Answer (score 2):

related: [When to use 'Entschuldigen Sie'](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15292/when-to-use-entschuldigen-sie)

You would use "Entschuldigen Sie (bitte), .." if you want something or just "Entschuldigung?" if it is clear what you want .. for example, if people block your way in the supermarket and you want to pass.

"Entschuldigung, dürfte ich kurz vorbei." would be the nicest. You can add that if the person is not getting what you want or if you want to be extra polite.

"Sorry" instead of "Entschuldigung" is shorter and very common today, but you would only use it if you are dealing with younger people.